# Error reading string path from file (escaping trouble)

Tags: c#, file-io, escaping

I have a json config file where I am trying to get the path of a file. It looks like this (in the json key entry):

""path"": ""\myfstore\xdrive\test\files\""

I read the json data into a property and
when I try to use it like this,

```
File.WriteAllBytes(myObj.Path + myObj.FileName, aBuffer);
```

I get the error: ""Could not find a part of the path 'c:\myfstore\xdrive\test\files\MyFile.txt'."

why is it putting c: i there? btw, myfstore is a network share.

And it works if I use a variable like this:

```
string path = @"\\myfstore\xdrive\test\files\" + myObj.FileName;
File.WriteAllBytes(path, aBuffer);
```

But I need to store these paths in a json file.

I have tried escaping it differently in the json file, but I either get a "illegal character" error or the above error - "could not find part of the path".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess it is because you have 2 backslashes in your string but only one on the JSON variable

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty obvious to me. In your first example you have this string:

```
\myfstore\xdrive\test\files\
```

and in your second example you have this string

```
\\myfstore\xdrive\test\files\
```

One is a network path, the other isn't.

Your json should have 2 back slashes at the beginning. NOT one.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, after typing the question on here and looking again it became obvious. I had to change the json value to:

"path": "\\myfstore\xdrive\test\files\"